# Why don't kohanim eat terumah nowadays?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, teruma

[Terumah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heave_offering) is a tithe that is given to kohanim. I have been told that kohanim are not allowed to eat terumah nowadays. Is this true? If so, why not?

Comment: Why should they? How do you know they don't? Please try to put a bit more effort into your questions than one run-on sentence. Did you try googling for answers? What did you find lacking in what you found?

Answer (score 3):

The *kohen* needs to be in a state of *taharah* (ritual purity) to eat *terumah*. Since without having a *parah adumah* (red heifer needed to eliminate the effects of the impurity of connecting with a human carcass) it is not possible to be in a state of *taharah* nowadays, the *terumah* is not eaten.

[Rambam Sefer Zeraim Trumot chapter 2 halacha 14](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/992028/jewish/Terumot-Chapter-2.htm)

> Terumah [must be given] to a priest whether it is in a state of ritual
>   purity or not. Even if all the grain or the wine became impure before
>   [terumah] was separated, he is obligated to separate the terumah that
>   is impure and give it to a priest, as [Numbers 18:8] states: "And
>   behold I have given you the watch over My terumah,"<sup>54</sup> i.e.,
>   whether it is pure or impure. The pure [terumah] may be eaten by the
>   priests and they can benefit from the impure [terumah] by burning
>   it.<sup>55</sup> If it is oil, it can be kindled [as fuel for a lamp].
>   If it is grain or the like, it can be used as fuel for an
>   oven.<sup>56</sup>
>
> <sup>54.</sup> In the verse, the noun terumah uses a plural form
>   alluding to two types of terumah: pure terumah and impure terumah. See
>   also Hilchot Ma'aser 6:2.
>
> <sup>55.</sup> It is forbidden to partake of it.
>
> <sup>56.</sup> It may not, however, be given to animals as animal
>   fodder. See Sefer HaMitzvot (positive commandment 90) which states
>   that it is a mitzvah to burn impure terumah. Impure terumah from
>   fruits that will not be useful as fuel must be buried.

See [this source](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/separating-terumah-and-maaser/) from Orthodox Union, in the section **Explanation of the Procedure** in the first item.

Comment: This is inaccurate. There is no Kareit for eating Terumah while impure. Also notably a Temei Met can eat Terumah from the Diaspora.

Comment: @DoubleAA removed reference to *kareis*, very surprised, I thought this was correct. So is the penalty regular *malkos*?

Comment: The punishment is Mitah Bidei Shamayim. But you writing that without a source is no better than me doing so. Don't trust me. Look it up!

Comment: @DoubleAA tried to look around but could not find a direct reference, which is why i asked you here. i always thought it was *kareis* and was wrong, apparently

Comment: @sabbahillel thank you so much for the edit, it is so much better now